# onblur event to contain an if statement and a function call

Tags: javascript, html, onblur

I have this code:

```
onblur="(if(this.value==''){this.value=this.title});validateText(this.value);"
```

I'm trying to to combine an if statement and a function call inside the onblur event, and as you guessed it it is not working. Is this even possible? if yes then how? since if i will create another function for the if it will take me more time since i need to assign id's again where in that way i can just easily change the value.

how will i work my way to solve this problem? any suggestion is very much welcome.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the parentheses:

```
onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=this.title};validateText(this.value);"
       ^^             no parentheses            ^^
```

Comment: i get validateText is not defined, but with parentheses i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Comment: @magicianIam - Well, is the `validateText` function declared before this element?

Comment: the script containing the validateText is called in the head.

Comment: nevermind it works fine now, i just had to change some part of my code. thank you :)